# How to customize ResetPasswordAsync Error messages - Asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In the `ResetPassword` page if user input mistake email or Manipulate code, **Invalid token.** error was shown.

How can I customize these Errors? For example show `Incorect Email you entered` instead `Invalid token.`

http://localhost:17594/Account/ResetPassword?userId=A&code=B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer here:

[How to Change Error message returned from "await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password)" ?](https://forums.asp.net/t/2034972.aspx?How%20to%20Change%20Error%20message%20returned%20from%20await%20UserManager%20CreateAsync%20user%20model%20Password%20)